# Alternative for handling requests using switch statement

Tags: php, http, cron, httprequest

I have to set up multiple cron jobs. Each cron will be a separate request to the server. So, I started by the following, where each request will be handled by a case inside the switch, but the cases are bound to increase and thus doesn't seem to me a very good idea.

```
require_once './invoice_cron.php';

$checkRequest = isset($_REQUEST['request']);

if($checkRequest) {
    $request_name = $_REQUEST['request'];
    switch($request_name) {
        case 'send_invoice':
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

What could be a better approach here?

Comment: I'd put the actions in seperate files in a subfolder and then `include("./actions/".$request_name.".php")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let there be a request handler interface:

```
<?php
  // CronRequests.php

  require_once __DIR__.'./autoload.php';

  $request_name = isset($_REQUEST['request']) ? 
                   (new _cron)->handler($_REQUEST['request']) : 
                   null ;
```

Make a class that could handle each request:

```
class _cron {

/**
 * List of possible requests
 * @var array
 */
 private static $REQUESTS = ['send_invoice','start_user_subscription'];

/**
 * HTTP request handler for all cron jobs
 * @param string $request_name Name of the request
*/
 public function handler($request_name) {
    $status = false;
    if(isset($request_name)) {
        $request_map = array_flip(self::$REQUESTS);
        if(isset($request_map[$request_name])) {
            $status = $this->$request_name();
        }
    }
    return $status;
 }
}
```

The list of requests are bound to increase, so it is necessary to search the list efficiently. So, here we do an array flip and check a key for existence.

Answer (score 0):

- for each request type must match a function
- all the types of requests must be defined in the system before start the processing
- if a request is not in the list => some logical response must happen

i will give you just simple example, you can develop it

```
class Request{

    private $REQUEST_TYPES = ['get_invoice', 'set_invoice', 'print_invoice'];

    public function handler($requestKey){
        foreach($this->REQUEST_TYPES as $type){
            if($requestKey == $type) $this->$type();
        }
        $this->handlerNotFound();
    }

    private function get_invoice(){
        //do some thing here
    }

    private function set_invoice(){
        //do some thing here
    }

    private function print_invoice(){
        //do some thing here
    }

    private function handlerNotFound(){
        //do some thing here
    }
}
```